# How we can use our dataset without load it every time we run code?

Tags: python, csv, bigdata, pickle

I have a project on taxi demand prediction, the data is 12GB csv file, 131 million records. After preprocessing the data, I want to save it as a pickle or something else. I'm try pickle but it does not work, I do not know what is the problem!

some lines of my code:

```
my_data=dd.read_csv(taxi_data.csv', parse_dates ['tpep_pickup_datetime', 'tpep_dropoff_datetime'])

with open('mydatapick.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(my_data,f)

pickle_in=open('mydatapick.pickle', 'rb')
my_data=pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

Comment: what is the error message?  Pandas tends to take a lot of space in memory.

Comment: If it is a DataFrame why not write it back to csv after it is processed?

Comment: `but it does not work` - ?? what goes wrong?

Comment: also pandas has included pickling, e.g. `df.to_pickle("path_to_file.pkl")` and `df = pd.read_pickle("path_to_file.pkl")`.  I would suggest testing this on a small (<100 line) version of your .csv to debug general read/write problems first.